# How apply onclick on div tag using className(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like

```
div class="ncf-container nfc-bottom-right">
<div class="ncf info">
<button>X</button>
<p class="nfc-message">New Notification</p>
</div>
</div>
```

how to apply `onclick` on div using class name(Javascript)?

Comment: What this `onclick` will do?

Comment: Use the jQuery class selector .theClassName

Comment: @brk this is the part of show notification , and onclick is for open popup on notification  Actually i can not use  any function on this div then how to create click event (click on this div tag)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add `event` Using `Jquery` and `javascript`.

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("nfc-bottom-right");
var myFunction = function() {
    alert('clicked javascript way');
};
for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}


$(".nfc-bottom-right").on("click",function(){
  alert('Jquery way');
})
```

```css
.nfc-bottom-right{
 border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ncf-container nfc-bottom-right">
<div class="ncf info">
<button>X</button>
<p class="nfc-message">New Notification</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

`$('info').on('click', function() {
    // ... your code to execute onClick
});`

Vanilla JS

`document.querySelector('.info').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // ... your code to execute onClick
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `onclick` behavior for a div tag, via class name in the following way:

```
<!-- This is your div, with custom class name -->
<div class="yourClassName">
Div Content
</div>

<script>
     document.querySelector('.yourClassName')
     .addEventListener('click', function() {

       // This is the logic that is run when the div with yourClassName class is clicked
       alert('the div was clicked');
     })
</script>
```